# transient mark mode highlighting not visible inside preview latex

Tags: latex, auctex, faces, colors, preview-latex

I am using preview latex in auctex. When you are inside
an equation there is a blue background around the latex you
are previewing, which means I cannot see the highlighing from
transient mark mode. The highlighing from transient mark mode
and preview latex are different colors so I do not believe
this is a color conflict. How can I disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the line `(overlay-put ov 'face 'preview-face)` from the function `preview-toggle` in `preview.el`.

In more detail, use `M-x find-function preview-toggle` (C-h C-f) to navigate to the relevant function, copy its contents into your init file, and delete the line that I mentioned.  Alternatively, use override advice.